# Best way to store enum values in database - String or Int

Tags: database, nhibernate, enums, fluent

I have a number of enums in my application
which are used as property type in some classes.

What is the best way to store these values in database, as String or Int?

FYI, I will also be mapping these attribute types using fluent Nhibernate.

Sample code:

```
public enum ReportOutputFormat
{
    DOCX,
    PDF,
    HTML
}

public enum ReportOutputMethod
{
    Save,
    Email,
    SaveAndEmail
}

public class ReportRequest
{
    public Int32 TemplateId
    {
        get { return templateId; }
        set { templateId = value; }
    }
    public ReportOutputFormat OutputFormat
    {
        get { return outputFormat; }
        set { outputFormat = value; }
    }

    public ReportOutputMethod OutputMethod
    {
        get { return outputMethod; }
        set { outputMethod = value; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Both have advantages. If you store them by their Integer value, then you must be careful editing your enumeration later on in your project. If somehow the integer values for the enumeration elements get redefined, all your data will be corrupted. But it will be the fastest/smallest datatype to use.

If you use the string representation you'll not have the redefined value problem for as long as you don't change the name of the elements in the enumeration. However strings take up more space in your database and are probably a bit more costly in use.

At the end, there's no definitive winner I guess.

**Edit**

Using the Integer value might be the best way. You can overcome the 'redefined value' problem for the enumeration elements, by setting the value for each element yourself. Indeed a good suggestion from Kevin.

Comment: I can't believe you'd even consider half-recommending an approach that could easily result in data corruption!  Just out of an imagined concern for compactness?  If the compactness concern is that strong, add an int field to the enum!  NEVER rely on the ordinal.  Read Effective Java.

Comment: I really don't see where I'm recommending anything to be honest. I'm only stating advantages and disadvantages. Though you have a point, not wanting to rely on the ordinal value, you might want to turn that 'fire' in your comment down a notch ;)

Comment: @KevinBourrillion What does "add an int field to the enum" mean?

Comment: @John he means assigning specific values to elements of the enumeration.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/enumeration-types for examples. That way, you leave nothing to chance.

Answer (score 45):

The implementation is easy in both cases, and performance differences should be minor.

Therefore, go for the meaning : **the Strings are more meaningful than numbers**, so use the String.

Comment: +1 I have worked with millions of records. Only then I realised meaning was a lot more important than "compactness".

Comment: Sometimes performance is more important, lest the meaning be lost. So pick your poison and determine which has more value.